# WPF WrapPanel and Scroll View only if elements inside reach a certain total

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WrapPanel inside a ScrollViewer.  I measured out my layout that if 6 buttons can only fit in a fixed area on the Window of a width of 1920. But what I now want is that if there are more than 6 buttons on the page, I want the scroll viewer to show and scroll horizontally.

My desired layout would be to have the initial layout be of 6 buttons.
2 rows x 3 in each row.  If there are more than 6, the next button(s) would show in the scrollable area triggering the scroll view to show.
I am thinking that I may need to dynamically create StackPanels with "groups" of 6 buttons.  If the button amount created is greater than 6, dynamically create a new StackPanel and add the next "group" of 6 buttons in that but then add that new StackPanel to the ScrollViewer.  Am I correct in this assumption or is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

(NOTE): I just found that I can not add more than one StackPanel to a ScrollViewer. So is there a better way to do this?

How would I achieve this?

This is my current XAML layout with my WrapPanel.

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0,100,0,0" Height="750" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="1920">
        <WrapPanel x:Name="stkPnlProductCategories" Height="Auto" Width="1920">

        <!-- This is filled in dynamically at runtime
            <controls:btnLarge Height="325" Width="500" Margin="20,0" TitleText="My Title" NoteText="" ShowNote="Collapsed" ShowSubTitle="Collapsed"/>
        -->

        </WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Can you bind to an items.count on your buttons and if > 6 do a change on like the VerticalScrollbarVisibility from `Disabled` to `True` on the ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so instead of making `<WrapPanel>` a fixed width, use something adaptable like a

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
```

The benefit of this, is that it will actually use that handy attribute of the `<ScrollViewer>` that you already have typed out there, `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`.

That ought to do the trick. I have to say though, you want to avoid hard-coding widths, like you seem to be doing a lot. Sometimes it even saves effort to have the width adapt to the window size. Just a thought.

Edit:
As far as trying to put in multiple `StackPanel`s into a `ScrollViewer`, `ScrollViewer`s can only contain one child element. That just means that if you want two `StackPanel`s inside, then you need to wrap them in something else. For instance, you can put just a simple `Grid`

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

or another `StackPanel`

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I tried using a StackPanel and all my buttons lined up horizontally and did not wrap and just ran off the side of the window.  I will try taking out the width's on those and follow the width of the Window. I may have to do a combo of what Chris above suggested too.  Hmm. This will be an interesting try.

Comment: I was under the impression that you WANT the buttons to run off the edge of the window if there are more than six, and you want to be able to scroll over to see them. Is that right?

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying.  I will update my questions with a screenshot of what I want to achieve. More or less I want the 6 buttons to show up in a grid, 2 rows x 3 in each row, IF the amount of buttons is greater than 6, then I want to more or less have the other buttons show in the overflowed scroll area.  Now that I think about it, I may need to dynamically create separate Stackpanels if the button count is greater than 6.

Comment: So you do not want to have to scroll horizontally to see extra buttons? Do you just want more and more rows of 3 buttons? I don't understand what you are trying to do, and how it might relate to horizontal scrolling.